# How to open word document file in terminal?

Tags: command-line, word-documents

As I'm trying to open a word document from the terminal, i used wvWare and some other commands for the same, but i couldn't get it.
Could any one please help me out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can open it with help of libre-office-writer by following command (open with libre office writer):

```
lowriter "<path/to/file>"
```

From `man libreoffice`:

```
Name
       libreoffice - LibreOffice office suite

SYNOPSIS
       libreoffice [--accept=accept-string] [--base] [--calc] [--convert-to output_file_extension[:output_filter_name] [--outdir
       output_dir] file]...  [--display display]  [--draw]  [--global]  [--headless]  [--help|-h|-?]  [--impress]  [--invisible]
       [--infilter=""]  [--math]  [--minimized]  [-n file]... [--nodefault] [--nolockcheck] [--nologo] [--norestore] [-o
       file]... [-p file...]  [--print-to-file [--printer-name printer_name] [--outdir output_dir] file]...   [--pt  printername
       file...]    [--show   Impress  file]...  [--unaccept=accept-string]  [--terminate_after_init]  [--view  file]...  [--web]
       [--writer]  [file...]
       lobase
       localc
       lodraw
       lofromtemplate
       loimpress
       lomath
       loweb
       lowriter

DESCRIPTION
       LibreOffice (LO for short) is a multi-platform office productivity suite.
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the other commands lines for opening the basic files, like pictures and all from the terminal.

Comment: @user3616399 use `cat "<filename>"` to display basic file and `eog "<filename>"` for image.

Answer (score 9):

Technically speaking `xdg-open` should work for *all* file types. It'll just open them in the appropriate application. All the document mime types are mapped to Libre Office by default so this should just work:

```
xdg-open document.doc
```

Comment: NO! its not working.. @Pandya was right.

Comment: @user3616399 worked for me. +1 for universal opener!

Comment: Works for me (on Ubuntu 16.04).  Upvoted this answer because I want the command line equivalent of finding the file in the file manager application and double-clicking it.  I shouldn't have to remember the application executable name (`lowriter` in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2):

It should work with Libre Office.

```
libreoffice document.docx
```

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me

`catdoc document.rf`

Answer (score 1):

To view a word document docx in terminal:

```
pandoc document.docx | lynx --stdin
```

You should have `pandoc` and `lynx`.